# Colouring text in C#

Tags: c#, colors, textbox, richtextbox, label

i am developing an IRC client in C# (Visual Studio 2010) and I want to colour the server text (e.g. the nicknames or the messages themselves) in different colors.

What would be the best way to do that? At the moment I have solved this by using the RichTextBox object.

Or would it be better to use a grid with labels?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It might be worth telling us if you're using WinForms or WPF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `RichTextBox` is perfectly suited for that task.

Answer (score 0):

When I developed a chat client for a university module I went with an HTML page and the list of messages. Each time a message came in I generated the HTML page and displayed it using an HTML renderer. This gave me complete control over the look and feel of the client.